# Haskell wx fails install Macosx

Tags: macos, haskell, wxhaskell

I was trying to get wxHaskell installed on my mac (Osx Mavericks). I fixed the issue with gcc, and I used brew to install wxmac (version 3.0). The issue that keeps coming up is that the hackage cabal searches for looks for wx 2.9, while I have 3.0. It says that it can't find:

```
 Warning: No config found to match: /usr/local/bin/wx-config --version=2.9 --version-full
               in /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.0.0/lib/wx/config
      If you require this configuration, please install the desired
      library build.  If this is part of an automated configuration
      test and no other errors occur, you may safely ignore it.
      You may use wx-config --list to see all configs available in
      the default prefix.
```

I can't find any way to install a different version of wx through brew. Does anyone have a fix?
Thanks!

Comment: According to the wxHaskell page on hackage, it only supports wxWidgets 2.9. So just get 2.9 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/2.9.5/) and make sure you are installing the latest version of wxHaskell.